# Is there a way this lambda can capture a copy of the pointer?

Tags: c++, lambda

In a lambda I'd like to capture a copy of a pointer, but can't because it's a static variable (can't capture it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class Window
{public:
    Window(std::string name) : name(name) {}
    std::function<void(int)> eventHandlerFunction;
    std::string name;
};

Window* ptr;

int main()
{
    Window* wnd1 = new Window("wnd1");
    Window* wnd2 = new Window("wnd2");
    ptr = wnd1;

    wnd1->eventHandlerFunction = [=](int n) { std::cout << ptr->name; }; 
// I'd like to capture a copy of the ptr value to wnd1 through the ptr variable

   // BECAUSE THEN
    ptr = wnd2;

    // SOME TIME DOWN THE TRACK THE MOUSE CURSOR ROLLS OVER wnd1, calls eventHandlerFunction
    // and prints "wnd2" instead of "wnd1".
}
```

Comment: Just copy it: [ptr=ptr]

Comment: Why not capture wnd1 or wnd2?

Comment: @Klaus Possibly the value of `ptr` isn't known at the time. The lambda should capture whatever value it has when it's created.

Comment: @Kevin If the value is not known, it is also not known in something different. If we can generate a copy in ptr from wnd1, we can copy wnd1.

Comment: @Klaus `if (user_input) ptr = wnd1; else ptr = wnd2;` What do you capture?

Comment: @Kevin: I can't catch the problem [ptr] captures a COPY of a pointer. So you have a second pointer and later changes will not change the captured one. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @Klaus The point is that the OP can't capture `ptr` because it's a static variable. Igor R. commented the solution (which should be made an answer)

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a typo, I fixed it. I don't understand the comment about "Just copy it [ptr = ptr], ptr is a static variable, even if in the lambda I do "Window* tempLocalPtr = ptr; tempLocalPtr->name;" it's still going to copy it when the lambda is called, meaning ptr could be pointing to osmething else

Comment: @Igor Oh you meant [ptr=ptr] in the capture parentheses, I'm afraid I don't understand syntax

Comment: The first `ptr` is a local variable inside the lambda. The second is the global you copy from. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Tf338x)

Comment: Why capture? Just copy it. `auto ptr = ::ptr;`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Inside, outside, whatever. Why exactly wouldn't it work?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah sorry that's a brain fart on my part. Should only copy outside.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Definitely! I'm sorry, I thought I accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy the current value of `ptr` with the lambda syntax `[local_copy=variable_to_copy_from]`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class Window {
public:
    Window(std::string name) : name(name) {}
    std::function<void(int)> eventHandlerFunction;
    std::string name;
};

Window* ptr;

auto get_ev_handler() {
    return [ptr=ptr](int n) { std::cout << n << ' ' << ptr->name << '\n'; };

    // You can name it something else if you'd like:
    //return [a_copy=ptr](int n) { std::cout << n << ' ' << a_copy->name << '\n'; };
}

int main() {
    Window* wnd1 = new Window("wnd1");
    Window* wnd2 = new Window("wnd2");

    ptr = wnd1;
    wnd1->eventHandlerFunction = get_ev_handler();
    ptr = wnd2;
    wnd2->eventHandlerFunction = get_ev_handler();
    ptr = nullptr;

    // here ptr == nullptr, but these still hold copies of the old values:
    wnd1->eventHandlerFunction(1);
    wnd2->eventHandlerFunction(2);
}
```